# Laravel PDF issue with getting image from Storage location

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-8, laravel-blade, dompdf

On using the following setups,

```
"php": "^7.3|^8.0",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
"fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
"laravel/framework": "^8.81",
```

the PDF works well in the local host and the Plesk server. But unfortunately, the PDF is not generating in the **greendc** Server.

The Laravel Controller code is:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/topicDetail',$topic); 
$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$fileName = 'export-'. date('m-d-Y-His').'.pdf';
Storage::put('public/uploads/docs/downloads/'.$fileName, $pdf->output());
$link =  Storage::disk('docs')->url('downloads/'.$fileName);
return $this->successResponse($link);
```

The Blade code snapshot is:

```
<td style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage//uploads/download/data/img/Pol_filled.png")?>" alt="img">
<img src="<?php echo asset("storage//uploads/download/data/img/Pol.png")?>" alt="img">
</td>
```

We getting a **strict-origin-when-cross-origin** error in the **greendc** Server, the Server is unable to access the image from the Storage folder.

So my query is:

1. Is this Server related error?
2. **greendc** Server never access the Storage (Symbolic links)?
3. using is not a proper method ?

we already given Storage link, other setup and all

Comment: Is it normal storage//uploads in path? With 2 /

Comment: Yes it is working fine in localhost, pleskserver @MisterDebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use "echo assets" in the blade file.

So use

```
<td style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
<img src="{{ public_path('uploads/download/data/img/Pol_filled.png') }}" alt="img">
<img src="{{ public_path('uploads/download/data/img/Pol.png') }}" alt="img">
</td>
```

this will works well for all types of images